# Expected Growth of General Pure Birth Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, birth-death-process

Assume we have a non-explosive Markov Chain $(X_t)_t$ in continuous time with Q matrix
$$
Q(k,l) = 
\begin{cases}
\lambda_k &\text{if } l=k+1\\ 
-\lambda_k &\text{if } l=k\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
i.e. $X$ is a pure birth process. Further we know that $0<\lambda_i < \lambda_j$ for all $i<j$.

What can we say about $\mathbb{E}[X_t]$ if $X$ starts in one a.s.?

First I tried to calculate the transition function using Kolmogorov's forward equation, but this ends in solving a tedious system of linear ODEs. Is there another way to give an expression for $\mathbb{E}[X_t]$?

I am happy about any kind of suggestion or help. Thank you.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795940/expected-value-of-a-simple-birth-process for the case where $\lambda_k=k\lambda$. For the general case, I suspect there is not a nice closed form.